# git : How to create patches series without merge commits to one file if commit message the same

Tags: git, directory, patch

I'd tried to create patches for specific directory under GIT. 
 
`git format-patch -o ../merge2 c872022f8^..HEAD app/my/dir` 
Everything is ok but some commits which consecutive and has the same commit message added to one file. I can't apply such commits. So I decided to find solution for put each commit into separated file but I haven't found it. How it can be done with one command?

Comment: So which step actually went wrong. Did you get a patch series from `format-patch`, and did it read as you would expect? Or is it an error from an unlisted `apply` command?

Comment: Seems, there is a problem with merge commits which have some changes. I don't know how to make right patches for them. But on these commits I'm getting errors.

Comment: Such merges are called 'evil' merges because it isn't clear how the extra changes arrived and which parent they should be attributed to. As a patch series it is usually a first parent diff without regard to any second parent contributions. see also http://git-blame.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/where-do-evil-merges-come-from.html